# Convert 6 digit number to time in asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Is there a function in .net that will take a number such as 134,501 and convert it to time? That time would be 1:45:01 pm. I was hoping i didn't have to reinvent the wheel for this.

Comment: Is the number a string such as "134,501", or an integer?

Comment: well I am retrieving this number from an as400 database and .net views this number as a double actually because i would get "can not convert double to datetime" error when trying to convert it before i knew what data type it was.

Comment: What is 134.501 ? Minutes / seconds ?

Comment: @Felice that would be 1:45:01 pm as stated above. :)

Comment: @Felice: It wasn't obvious to me either.  It's HHmmss format, so 13 hours, 45 minutes, 01 seconds.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming you're using today's date:

```
int timeNumber = 134501;
DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact(timeNumber.ToString().PadLeft(6, '0'), "HHmmss", null);
```

Comment: +1@AlexWalker but you should add PadLeft(6, '0') to the ToString(). Otherwise it will fail for AM values

Comment: @Conrad You are correct! Thank you very much for that bit of information.